# Adjust appearance of text table in printed layout with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

How do I adjust text size and border width of `QgsLayoutItemTextTable` in `QgsLayout`? I would like to have text smaller and borders thinner.

Here is my code which adds the table to layout.

```
composition = QgsLayout(QgsProject.instance())
table = QgsLayoutItemTextTable(composition)
composition.addMultiFrame(table)

# Add columns abd fill with data
fields = ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3']
cols = [QgsLayoutTableColumn(), QgsLayoutTableColumn(), QgsLayoutTableColumn()]
for n in range(0, len(fields)):
    cols[n].setHeading(fields[n])
table.setColumns(cols)
table.setContents(data)

# Add frame
frame = QgsLayoutFrame(composition, table)
frame.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(20, 500), True)
frame.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 470, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
table.addFrame(frame)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following lines:

```
# table grid stroke
table.setGridStrokeWidth(0.1) # 0.1 mm

# content text
content_text_format = QgsTextFormat()
content_text_format.setSize(15)
table.setContentTextFormat(content_text_format)

# header text
header_text_format = QgsTextFormat()
header_text_format.setSize(20)
table.setHeaderTextFormat(header_text_format)
```

You also may need to use `frame.setFrameEnabled(False)`.

[image]

Comment: I used 15 and 20 to show the difference. Of course, you need to keep it small.